# autowired attribute not getting set

Tags: java, spring

I am attempting a java application that has two beans it gets through Spring, one retrieved by name and one autowired.  Here is that code:

```
package firstspring;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class FirstSpring
{
  private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FirstSpring.class);

  @Autowired
  private Car currentCar;
  public void setCurrentCar(Car car) { this.currentCar = car; }
  public Car getCurrentCar() { return currentCar; }

  private static void say(String message) { System.out.println(message); }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    FirstSpring firstSpring = new FirstSpring();
    firstSpring.go();
  }

  public void go()
  {
    logger.info("here we go");
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/appContext.xml");
    Car firstCar = (Car)appContext.getBean("firstCar");

    say ("firstCar was " + firstCar.getColor());
    say ("currentCar is " + currentCar.getColor());

  }

}
```

and its configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xsi:schemaLocation=
            "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

      <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="firstCar" class="firstspring.Car">
        <property name="color" value="blue" />
        <property name="doors" value="2" />
        <property name="transmission" value="automatic" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="currentCar" class="firstspring.Car" >
        <property name="color" value="red" />
        <property name="doors" value="4" />
        <property name="transmission" value="5-speed" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="firstSpring" class="firstspring.FirstSpring">
            <property name="currentCar" ref="currentCar" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And the Car class just to make it complete:

```
package firstspring;

public class Car
{
  String  color;
  int     doors;
  String  transmission;

  public String getColor() { return color; }
  public void setColor(String color) { this.color = color; }

  public int getDoors() { return doors; }
  public void setDoors(int doors) { this.doors = doors; }

  public String getTransmission() { return transmission; }
  public void setTransmission(String transmission) { this.transmission = transmission; }
}
```

I get a null pointer exception:

```
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5e6458a6: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,firstCar,currentCar,firstSpring,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at firstspring.FirstSpring.go(FirstSpring.java:33)
    at firstspring.FirstSpring.main(FirstSpring.java:23)
firstCar was blue
```

I've tried various other things -- putting 'byName' on the currentCar bean in the configuration, but I don't think that's necessary according to what documentation I've read.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Try using `@Qualifier`s

Comment: I'm trying to learn very basic Spring; after that I can branch out into other parts of it.  I've not read anything about @Qualifier being necessary.

Comment: Why a downvote? This is a well-asked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say `new FirstSpring()`, you're creating your own instance of that class which is outside of Spring's control, so Spring can't autowire it. Therefore when you get to `currentCar.getColor()`, `currentCar` is null. For this to work properly, you'd need to create your `ApplicationContext` in the main method, get the `FirstSpring` instance from Spring, and invoke `go()` on that instead of creating the object yourself.

In short, Spring cannot and will not manage (that is, autowire, initialize, destroy, etc.) any object that it didn't create itself.*

*Unless you're using [AspectJ with bytecode weaving](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) to accomplish this, but that's a rather advanced topic that you probably don't want to touch yet, unless you have other experience with AspectJ.

Comment: Thanks -- good answer: what to do and why.  I've submitted an edit to change "get the FirstCar instance from Spring" to "get the FirstSpring instance from Spring", since that's obviously what you meant ("and invoke go() on that").  I also learned that Spring won't process the XML file if you've indented the first line...

Comment: Good call on the edit. As for the blank space in the XML, that's not a Spring thing. It's required by the XML spec that a prolog (your first line) be the very first thing in the file, even including white space.